# Combine mysql arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have two arrays

**array1**:

```
  [0]=>array(
     ['user']=>'name1',
     ['age']=>'28'     
  ),
  [1]=>array(
     ['user']=>'name2',
     ['age']=>'58'     
  ),
  [2]=>array(
     ['user']=>'name3',
     ['age']=>'15'     
  )
```

**array2**

```
  [0]=>array(
     ['user']=>'name3',
     ['sex']=>'male'     
  ),
  [1]=>array(
     ['user']=>'name1',
     ['sex']=>'male'     
  ),
  [2]=>array(
     ['user']=>'name2',
     ['sex']=>'female'
  )
```

**Expecting result**

```
  [0]=>array(
     ['user']=>'name1',
     ['age']=>'28',
     ['sex']=>'male'     
  ),
  [1]=>array(
     ['user']=>'name2',
     ['age']=>'58',
     ['sex']=>'male'     
  ),
  [2]=>array(
     ['user']=>'name3',
     ['age']=>'15',
     ['sex']=>'female'
  )
```

I have tried lot of ways **array_merge**, **array_combine**  . But i dont know where i did mistakes. please help me

Comment: I think this only php question not mysql/

Comment: @MahdiParsa.. I am getting this result from mysql query only...Sorry.. Can u help me..

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469803/php-merging-two-array-into-one-array-also-remove-duplicates

Comment: this can be done with php, but it's probably better to join the 2 queries, can you share them please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you cannot find built-in function to match your particular case (and there will be plenty of such cases), then maybe you have to try by yourself?

Map the arrays by the `name` key and fill a new one:

```
<?php
$arr1 =array ( 0=>array(
     'user'=>'name1',
     'age'=>'28'     
  ),
  1=>array(
     'user'=>'name2',
     'age'=>'58'     
  ),
  2=>array(
     'user'=>'name3',
     'age'=>'15'     
  )
);

$arr2 =array (0=>array(
     'user'=>'name3',
     'sex'=>'male'     
  ),
  1=>array(
     'user'=>'name1',
     'sex'=>'male'     
  ),
  2=>array(
     'user'=>'name2',
     'sex'=>'female'
  )
);

$result = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($arr2 as $k => $v) {
        if($value['user'] == $v['user']) {
            $result[$k]['user'] = $arr1[$k]['user'];
            $result[$k]['age'] = $arr1[$k]['age'];
            $result[$k]['sex'] = $arr2[$k]['sex'];
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result);

array (size=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'user' => string 'name2' (length=5)
      'age' => string '58' (length=2)
      'sex' => string 'male' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'user' => string 'name3' (length=5)
      'age' => string '15' (length=2)
      'sex' => string 'female' (length=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'user' => string 'name1' (length=5)
      'age' => string '28' (length=2)
      'sex' => string 'male' (length=4)
```

You can use sort to sort by keys:

```
sort($result);
var_dump($result);

array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'user' => string 'name1' (length=5)
      'age' => string '28' (length=2)
      'sex' => string 'male' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'user' => string 'name2' (length=5)
      'age' => string '58' (length=2)
      'sex' => string 'male' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'user' => string 'name3' (length=5)
      'age' => string '15' (length=2)
      'sex' => string 'female' (length=6)
```

Comment: The only answer that actually does what he asked for. +1.

Answer (score -1):

I would use [array_merge](https://www.php.net/array_merge)

Like below..

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

Then use [array_unique](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to get the unique values.

Comment: thanks u for ur response. I tried this but not working