# Removing duplicates in an array having Apache_Solr_Document object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, solr

**Updated:** I have two separate arrays which hold some data returned from search() function of SolrPhpClient. The arrays contain data in form of Apache_Sole_Document objects. These objects in turn contain the actual fields and values. I merge these two arrays to get a single array holding all items using `array_merge()` of PHP

The array will have some duplicate items which needs to be removed. 
I am not sure how to achieve it in this structure.

The array structure is as such:

```
Array ( [0] => Apache_Solr_Document Object ( 
            [_documentBoost:protected] => 
            [_fields:protected] => Array ( [id] => 111 [name] => ABCD ) 
            [_fieldBoosts:protected] => Array ( [id] => [name] => ) 
        ) 
        [1] => Apache_Solr_Document Object (
            [_documentBoost:protected] => 
            [_fields:protected] => Array ( [id] => 222 [name] => DEFG ) 
            [_fieldBoosts:protected] => Array ( [id] => [name] => ) 
        )
        [2] => Apache_Solr_Document Object (
            [_documentBoost:protected] => 
            [_fields:protected] => Array ( [id] => 333 [name] => LMNO ) 
            [_fieldBoosts:protected] => Array ( [id] => [name] => ) 
        )
        [3] => Apache_Solr_Document Object (
            [_documentBoost:protected] => 
            [_fields:protected] => Array ( [id] => 111 [name] => ABCD ) 
            [_fieldBoosts:protected] => Array ( [id] => [name] => ) 
        )
        [4] => Apache_Solr_Document Object (
            [_documentBoost:protected] => 
            [_fields:protected] => Array ( [id] => 444 [name] => PQRS ) 
            [_fieldBoosts:protected] => Array ( [id] => [name] => ) 
        )
        [5] => Apache_Solr_Document Object (
            [_documentBoost:protected] => 
            [_fields:protected] => Array ( [id] => 222 [name] => DEFG ) 
            [_fieldBoosts:protected] => Array ( [id] => [name] => ) 
        )       
    )
```

As you can see there is a [id] field and a [name] field.

I would like to remove duplicates from the array comparing the [id] field.

The final array after removing duplicates should look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Apache_Solr_Document Object (
            [_documentBoost:protected] => 
            [_fields:protected] => Array ( [id] => 111 [name] => ABCD ) 
            [_fieldBoosts:protected] => Array ( [id] => [name] => ) 
        ) 
        [1] => Apache_Solr_Document Object (
            [_documentBoost:protected] => 
            [_fields:protected] => Array ( [id] => 222 [name] => DEFG ) 
            [_fieldBoosts:protected] => Array ( [id] => [name] => ) 
        )
        [2] => Apache_Solr_Document Object (
            [_documentBoost:protected] => 
            [_fields:protected] => Array ( [id] => 333 [name] => LMNO ) 
            [_fieldBoosts:protected] => Array ( [id] => [name] => ) 
        )
        [3] => Apache_Solr_Document Object (
            [_documentBoost:protected] => 
            [_fields:protected] => Array ( [id] => 444 [name] => PQRS ) 
            [_fieldBoosts:protected] => Array ( [id] => [name] => ) 
        )   
    )
```

How can I achieve this? somebody please help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could iterate over the array and remove the duplicates, but that doesn't seem like a neat solution to me.

I'm not familiar with the SolrPhpClient, but Solr does support grouping on fields. You can group on the id by adding this part to your request:

```
group=true&group.field=id
```

The documents returned will be grouped on the id. For more details check [this](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) page.

**Update:**

I looked at the SolrPhpClient documentation and  see that you can add additional parameters to your request like this:

```
$additionalParameters = array(
      'fq' => 'a filtering query',
      'facet' => 'true',
      'facet.field' => array(
           'field_1',
           'field_2'
   )
);
$results = $solr->search($query, $start, $rows, $additionalParameters);
```

I assume you can add the grouping parameters to this:

```
$additionalParameters = array(
   'group' => 'true',
   'group.field' => 'id'
    )
);
$results = $solr->search($query, $start, $rows, $additionalParameters);
```

For more details on this, check [this](https://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/wiki/FAQ#How_Can_I_Use_Additional_Parameters_%28like_fq,_facet,_etc%29) page

Comment: I have used the grouping options as well. One thing I forgot to mention is that I am merging one more array with the result array. That is where duplicates are formed. Currently I am using this `$unique_docs = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $duplicate_docs), SORT_REGULAR));`. I am not sure how effective it is, but it gives me the desired result.

Comment: Okay. What kind of array are you merging with the result array? Is this also a result set from Solr? If this is the case, a good question to ask yourself would be do I need to send two requests to Solr to get the results I need? Maybe you can update your question a bit to provide more background information so I can help you further.

Comment: Okay. I'm curious why you are having these two arrays that need merging in the first place? What kind of queries are you sending to Solr? And do you need to send two queries to Solr to get these results? Sure, you can merge the two arrays, removing the duplicates after the request as you described in you previous comment. But I think it's better to solve the problem at it's source, if possible ofcourse.

Comment: Its kinda complicated but yes I need to send two queries to Solr from the same table in database on specifying certain conditions. I get two result arrays and I need the results of the two arrays to be displayed under one tab in my PHP application. So I need to merge the two arrays and then check for any duplicates and remove them. At present I'm using the `array_map()` function to remove duplicates as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I am wondering whether I can set the `array_map()` function as the correct answer..

Comment: I'm not that experienced with PHP. So I can't tell you if it's the most efficient solution. I did come across this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469803/php-merging-two-array-into-one-array-also-remove-duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469803/php-merging-two-array-into-one-array-also-remove-duplicates). I hope this helps.