# how to remove array values with similar key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new and this might be simple one. I have two arrays. And I want to remove arrays with same keys.

Array One Example like this

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => abc
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => def
        )
    [12] => Array
        (
            [name] => XYZ
        )
)
```

and Array Two like this

```
Array
(
    [18] => Array
        (
            [name] => gty
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => def
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => FER
        )
)
```

I want to get result by removing the same key from the given two arrays. In my example array with key [4]. like

Result as

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => abc
        )
    [12] => Array
        (
            [name] => XYZ
        )
    [18] => Array
        (
            [name] => gty
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => FER
        )
)
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far to get the desired output? Show us your efforts so that we can help you to correct them in a proper way.

Comment: array_merge(
array_diff_key($array1, $array2),
array_diff_key($array2, $array1)
)

Comment: @KostiaShiian : thanks.. i think yours work.. I got the desired output. but the keys are all changed as 0,1,2,3,... not get the exact key as 1,12,18,7.. Its Ok i will manage somehow.. thanks again

Comment: @Suraj Lois: you are right. Just try  the + array union operator instead of array_mege. More details here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2), SORT_REGULAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_diff_key($array1, $array2, etc.)`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use se array_unique()

Answer (score 0):

You can  refer the following URL in stack overflow itself

[PHP - Merging two array into one array (also Remove Duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469803/php-merging-two-array-into-one-array-also-remove-duplicates)

Another way your solution is

```
array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2)
```