# Array remove the same php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fileid] => 7
            [remarks] => 
            [filename] => whomovedmycheese - Copy.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [size] => 500624
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fileid] => 7
            [remarks] => 
            [filename] => whomovedmycheese.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [size] => 500624
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fileid] => 8
            [remarks] => 
            [filename] => whomovedmycheese - Copy.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [size] => 500624
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fileid] => 8
            [remarks] => 
            [filename] => whomovedmycheese.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [size] => 500624
        )

)
```

This is my array I want to remove duplicate. I tried to remove the duplicated using below code.

```
$input4 = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $basicinfo3)));
$new_data3 = array_values($input4);
```

But the result is still the same as the starting array. In the above code the `$basicinfo` has the value of the array above.What i want to do is remove the duplicate array so it will look like this below.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [fileid] => 7
                [remarks] => 
                [filename] => whomovedmycheese - Copy.pdf
                [type] => application/pdf
                [size] => 500624
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [fileid] => 7
                [remarks] => 
                [filename] => whomovedmycheese.pdf
                [type] => application/pdf
                [size] => 500624
            )
    )
```

`UPDATE`

```
 Array
(
    [008-408-601-000-0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 008-408-601-000
            [lastname] => Smith
            [firstname] => John
            [email] => John@yahoo.com
            [Address] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => C++
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => C++
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => C++
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => Java
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => Java
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => Java
                        )

                )

        )

    [002-408-641-000-0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 008-408-601-000
            [lastname] => Smith
            [firstname] => Jack
            [email] => Jack@yahoo.com
            [Address] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => C++
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => C++
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => C++
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => Java
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => Java
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => Java
                        )

                )

        )

    [001-002-003-000-0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 008-408-601-000
            [lastname] => Smith
            [firstname] => Jean
            [email] => Jean@yahoo.com
            [Address] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => C++
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => C++
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => C++
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => Java
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => Java
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [Language] => Java
                        )

                )

        )







)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you please explain with example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use that function above since this takes into account the whole array batch for uniqueness, as you can already see, some `fileid` differs already with the same filename. If you need it based on `filename`, then a normal loop should suffice.

In your sample output, it seems the first ones found are priority then a simple `isset` should be okay.

```
$input4 = array();
foreach($basicinfo3 as $values) {
    if(!isset($input4[$values['filename']])) {
        $input4[$values['filename']] = $values; // if doesn't exist yet, push it
    }
}

$input4 = array_values($input4); // simple reindex
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/97EZZp)

Comment: Just a question i want advice on fileid is the id of the entry in database the increment id is it the better parameter to check than the filename?

Comment: @HogRider well, most OS i know doesn't allow duplicate filenames, so yes, you need to go with the file name not the incremented id

Comment: what is OS sorry havent encountered that term yet

Comment: @HogRider what i meant is operating system, all filenames sohuld be unique, (that would be weird if it allows it)

Comment: i have a question another question i wont post another because it is related here what if i have another array inside the array how can i manage the duplicate in the inside array?i will post a sample array in update

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array_unique($oldArray, SORT_REGULAR);
```

See: [PHP - Merging two array into one array (also Remove Duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469803/php-merging-two-array-into-one-array-also-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular php arrays to achieve this.

```
<?php
$data = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            "fileid" => 7,
            "remarks" => '',
            "filename" => "whomovedmycheese - Copy.pdf",
            "type" => "application/pdf",
            "size" => "500624",
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            "fileid"=> 7,
             "remarks" => '',
            "filename"=> "whomovedmycheese.pdf",
            "type"=> "application/pdf",
            "size" => "500624",
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            "fileid"=> 8,
             "remarks"=> '',
            "filename"=> "whomovedmycheese - Copy.pdf",
             "type"=> "application/pdf",
            "size" => "500624",
        ),

    3 => Array
        (
            "fileid"=> 8,
             "remarks"=> '',
            "filename"=> "whomovedmycheese.pdf",
             "type"=> "application/pdf",
            "size" => "500624",
        )
);

$newArray = array();
foreach ($data as $file)
{
   $newArray[$file['filename']] = $file;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
?>
```