# merge two array value in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to merge two array in laravel 5.3.I have variable '$type' which return

```
`Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [1] => rinu )`
```

which is get from the query

```
$type0=DB::table('users')->where('name','=',$head)->pluck('name','id');
```

I want to merge with array $type1 which returns

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [2] => john ) ) 
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [3] => dinesh ) )
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [4] => mahesh ) ) 
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) )

$type1=DB::table('users')->where('name','=',$head)->pluck('name','id');
```

I tried to merge and store it in $type0;

```
$type0=$type0->merge($type1);
```

It return wrong value

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => rinu [1] => john ) ) 
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => rinu [1] => john [2] => dinesh ) ) 
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => rinu [1] => john [2] => dinesh [3] => mahesh ) ) 
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => rinu [1] => john [2] => dinesh [3] => mahesh ) )`

enter code here
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to recieve merged `array` (and not `collection`), you can use [`toArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-toarray) and [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) functions:

```
$mergedArray = array_merge($type0->toArray(), $type1->toArray());
```

Comment: caught FATALERROREXCEPTION IN 7BB347C8C194579700A647DADD62EA3D8E0AB68A.PHP LINE 358:
CALL TO A MEMBER FUNCTION TOARRAY() ON ARRAY

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a Collection for each value. So you are probably fetching each value independently instead of in one go.

Your problem is probably solved by using [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses) instead of a number of `where`s.

```
$result = DB::table('users')
            ->whereIn('name', ['John', 'Dinesh', 'Mahesh'])
            ->get();
```