# How can I merge the elements of three arrays with same ID's?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have 3 database queries (For query results overview see below!).

How can I **merge the elements** of this three arrays (with more than 200.000 products in DB) together without duplicate array keys and values as the following example?

Desired result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 42710
            [imageName] => somthing
            [image] => https://www.somthing.com/image.jpg
            [loyality] => 122                
            [p_num] => 8
            [cpc] => 2
        )

    [...]    
)
```

I have tried to use array functions **`array_merge`**, **`array_merge_recursive`**, **`array_replace`**, **`array_replace_recursive`** and **`array_unique`**. But I could not merge clearly all arrays together.

---

Result of query 1 (>200000 total):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 42710
            [imageName] => somthing
            [image] => https://www.somthing.com/image.jpg
        )

     [...]
)
```

Result of query 2 (1450 total):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 42710
            [loyality] => 122
        )

    [...]

)
```

Result of query 3 (1820 total):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 42710
            [p_num] => 8
            [cpc] => 2
        )

    [...]

)
```

Note: Please don't make a suggestion based on *"SQL JOIN clause"*.

I am using PHP5.6, Symfony2, Doctrine2 and MySQL 5.5.52.

Comment: May be This could be already asked in this post?
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469803/php-merging-two-array-into-one-array-also-remove-duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469803/php-merging-two-array-into-one-array-also-remove-duplicates)

Comment: You're pulling 200k rows from database just to filter 99% of them out?

Comment: Does the `[id]` represent exactly the same thing for each array? I'm wondering because below you mention having 2 arrays each with an age but with different values?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could find a better solution for large arrays.

First fetching data through a custom repository:

```
$this->productAttributes = $this->manager->getRepository('ProductBundle:Rating')->findAllAttributeOfProducts();
$this->productOnlineDate = $this->manager->getRepository('ProductBundle:Rating')->findOnlineDate();
$this->numberOfClicks    = $this->manager->getRepository('ProductBundle:Rating')->findNumberOfClicks();
```

Second find productID in all arrays by means of `array_search` and `array_column`:

```
$findNumberOfClicks = array_search($this->arrayKey['id'], array_column($this->numberOfClicks, 'id'));
$findOnlineDate     = array_search($this->arrayKey['id'], array_column($this->productOnlineDate, 'id'));
```

Third merge arrays all together:

```
$this->productAttributes = $this->manager->getRepository('ProductBundle:Rating')->findAllAttributeOfProducts();
$this->productOnlineDate = $this->manager->getRepository('ProductBundle:Rating')->findOnlineDate();
$this->numberOfClicks    = $this->manager->getRepository('ProductBundle:Rating')->findNumberOfClicks();

$this->arrayMergedResult = [];

            foreach ($this->productAttributes as $this->product => $this->arrayKey) {

                // find product ID in all arrays
                $findNumberOfClicks = array_search($this->arrayKey['id'], array_column($this->numberOfClicks, 'id'));
                $findOnlineDate     = array_search($this->arrayKey['id'], array_column($this->productOnlineDate, 'id'));

                // merge arrays
                switch (true) {
                    case ($findOnlineDate === false && $findNumberOfClicks === false):
                        $this->arrayMergedResult = $this->arrayKey;
                        break;
                    case ($findOnlineDate === false):
                        $this->arrayMergedResult = $this->arrayKey + $this->numberOfClicks[$findNumberOfClicks];
                        break;
                    case ($findNumberOfClicks === false):
                        $this->arrayMergedResult = $this->arrayKey + $this->productOnlineDate[$findOnlineDate];
                        break;
                    default:
                        $this->arrayMergedResult = $this->arrayKey + $this->numberOfClicks[$findNumberOfClicks] + $this->productOnlineDate[$findOnlineDate];
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_merge` function to merge the results, to clarify things take a look at following example:

```
<?php

$resultSet1=[['id' => '32','name' => 'john'], ['id' => '15','name' => 'amin']];
$resultSet2=[['id' => '32','lastname' => 'doe'],['id' => '15','lastname' => 'alizade']];
$resultSet3=[['id' => '32','age' => '28'], ['id' => '15','age' => '25']];

$resultSet = array_merge($resultSet1, $resultSet2, $resultSet3);

$result = [];
foreach ($resultSet as $record) {   
    $key = $record['id'];
    if (array_key_exists($key, $result)) {
        $result[$key] = array_merge($result[$key], $record);
    }else{
        $result[$key] = $record;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Unfortunately its wrong.
Add one more array with different 'id' und different age value and see result.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse each array like this way, save the elements in result array `$o`.

```
$o = [];
array_walk($array1, function($v) use (&$o) {
    foreach($v as $key => $value) {
        $o[$v['id']][$key] = $value;
    }
});
```