# Comparing two arrays to find difference using PHP function

Tags: php, php-7

Using PHP in magento2, I need to compare two arrays. **$Session** array size will be larger than **$post** array size. So I need to compare my $post values with $session values. If both arrays have same values for all the keys, then empty array should be returned.

```
$session = [
    "domains" => 'x',
    "domain" => '',
    "searchfilter" => 'AD DOmain',
    "searchterm" => ''
];
$post = [
    "domains" => 'xx',
    "domain" => 'AD DOmain',
    "searchfilter" => ''
];
$result = $this->formArray($post, $session) ;
```

My Expected Result:

```
Array()
{
  "domains" => 'xx',
  "domain" => 'AD DOmain',
  "searchfilter" => ''
}
```

My Actual result:

```
Array()
{
}
```

I have tried something like,

```
public function formArray($post, $session){
        $checkNewValue = array_diff($post, $session);
        $checkNewKey = array_diff_key($post, $session);
        $mergedArray = array_merge($checkNewValue, $checkNewKey);
        return $mergedArray;
}
```

I don't know what am missing. Please help! Thank you

Comment: If the problem was solved, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

From this question: [PHP - Merging two arrays into one array (also Remove Duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469803/php-merging-two-arrays-into-one-array-also-remove-duplicates)

```
$session = [
    "domains" => 'x',
    "domain" => '',
    "searchfilter" => 'AD DOmain',
    "searchterm" => ''
];
$post = [
    "domains" => 'xx',
    "domain" => 'AD DOmain',
    "searchfilter" => ''
];
//This will return true if both `$session` and `$post` has the same key/value pair. 

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

`$a == $b   Equality    TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.`

if($session == $post){
     $new_arr = array();
}else{
     $new_arr = array_unique(array_merge($session,$post), SORT_REGULAR);    
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_arr);
```

Results to:

```
//if array are not equal

Array
(
    [domains] => xx
    [domain] => AD DOmain
    [searchfilter] => 
)

  //else
   Array()
```

Comment: What if $post array is similar to $session array. It should return an empty array for me. But it is returning $session array

Comment: @KNandy please specify that in your question. Also, define similar? are the values the same? Also, write that in your question.

Comment: @KNandy just to clarify if they have equal key/value pair? because your `$session` has 4 key/value pair while `$post` has three.

Answer (score 1):

[array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) can be used here.

> array_diff_assoc — Computes the difference of arrays with
>   additional index check

Answer (score 1):

Try to use array_diff_assoc.

```
<?php
$session = [
    "domains" => 'x',
    "domain" => '',
    "searchfilter" => 'AD DOmain',
    "searchterm" => ''
];
$post = [
    "domains" => 'xx',
    "domain" => 'AD DOmain',
    "searchfilter" => ''
];

$checkNewValue = array_diff_assoc($post, $session);
var_dump($checkNewValue);

?>
```