# How to combine array with same element value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My array data :

```
$opt_val = 
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0|0|0|P3D
                        [1] => 0|0|1|P4D
                        [2] => 0|0|2|P5D
                    )
    
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0|1|0|P3D
                        [1] => 0|1|1|P4D
                        [2] => 0|1|2|P5D
                    )
    
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1|0|0|P3D
                        [1] => 1|0|1|P4D
                        [2] => 1|0|2|P5D
                    )
    
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1|1|0|P3D
                        [1] => 1|1|1|P4D
                        [2] => 1|1|2|P5D
                    )
    
            )
    
    )
```

I want to join above array with result :

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0|0|0|P3D#0|1|0|P3D (from Array[0][0][0]#Array[0][1][0])
                [1] => 0|0|1|P4D#0|1|1|P4D
                [2] => 0|0|2|P5D#0|1|2|P5D
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1|0|0|P3D#1|1|0|P3D (from Array[1][0][0]#Array[1][1][0])
                [1] => 1|0|1|P4D#1|1|1|P4D
                [2] => 1|0|2|P5D#1|1|2|P5D
            )

    )
```

My code

```
for ($ov = 0; $ov < count($opt_val); $ov++) {
    for ($ovi = 0; $ovi < count($opt_val[$ov]); $ovi++) {
        for ($iv = 0; $iv < count($opt_val[$ov][$iv]); $iv++) {
            $im_opt_val[$iv] = implode("#", $opt_val[$ov][$ovi]);
        }
        $impl_opt_val[$ov] = $im_opt_val;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Merging two arrays into one array (also Remove Duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469803/php-merging-two-arrays-into-one-array-also-remove-duplicates)

Comment: I think that is not merge array, but combine array from thirth element from first array become to be second example above

Comment: I think I understand -- you want to combine the innermost arrays, regardless of duplicates, and nest with only one level of nesting. Manually with a loop is the best thing I can think of. I would create a function to extract an array value at a certain level of nesting, call that in a loop to build up your result array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet should do the trick.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

$opt_val = [
    [
        [
            '0|0|0|P3D',
            '0|0|1|P4D',
            '0|0|2|P5D',
        ],
        [
            '0|1|0|P3D',
            '0|1|1|P4D',
            '0|1|2|P5D',
        ],
    ],
    [
        [
            '1|0|0|P3D',
            '1|0|1|P4D',
            '1|0|2|P5D',
        ],
        [
            '1|1|0|P3D',
            '1|1|1|P4D',
            '1|1|2|P5D',
        ],
    ],
];

$result = [];
foreach ($opt_val as $outerArrayKey => $outerArray) {
    foreach ($outerArray as $innerArray) {
        foreach ($innerArray as $innerArrayKey => $innerArrayElement) {
            if (!isset($result[$outerArrayKey][$innerArrayKey])) {
                $result[$outerArrayKey][$innerArrayKey] = $innerArrayElement;
            } else {
                $result[$outerArrayKey][$innerArrayKey] .= '#'.$innerArrayElement;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

The output would be:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "0|0|0|P3D#0|1|0|P3D"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "0|0|1|P4D#0|1|1|P4D"
    [2]=>
    string(19) "0|0|2|P5D#0|1|2|P5D"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "1|0|0|P3D#1|1|0|P3D"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "1|0|1|P4D#1|1|1|P4D"
    [2]=>
    string(19) "1|0|2|P5D#1|1|2|P5D"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this work for you:

```
$finalFinalArray = [];
foreach($outerArray as $key => $innerArray){
  $finalArray = [];
  $inQueueArray = [];
  foreach ($innerArray as $inInnerArray) {
    $inQueueArray = array_merge($inQueueArray, $inInnerArray);
  }
  // Now, inner array is merged
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($inQueueArray); $i++){
    $finalArray[] = $inQueueArray[$i] + "#" + $inQueueArray[$i+3];
  }
  $finalFinalArray[] = $finalArray;
}
var_dump($finalFinalArray);
```

Didn't test it!

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but unfortunatelly it's still not work. I have result Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
        )

)

Comment: Edited, test it again

Comment: Thank you for your edited, but there's an error : Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered