# Loop two arrays without duplicate values from the first array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not 100% sure about the title (something is missing), but I'm 100% sure what output I need.

```
$A = array('0' => '1451', '1' => '1451', '2' => '1452', '3' => '1452', '4' => '1453', '5' => '1453', '6' => '1457', '7' => '1460');
$B = array('0' => '22',   '1' => '23',   '2' => '22',   '3' => '23',   '4' => '22',   '5' => '23',   '6' => '',     '7' => '');
    
          for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($A); $i<$n; $i++) {
               echo $A[$i] . ' = ' . $B[$i] . '<br />';
          }
          echo '<hr></hr>';
          echo 'I need this output, is possible: 
          1451 = 22, 23<br />
          1452 = 22, 23<br />
          1453 = 22, 23<br />
          1457 =<br />
          1460 = ';
```

You can run the code here: https://extendsclass.com/php-bin/3baf302

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Merging two arrays into one array (also Remove Duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469803/php-merging-two-arrays-into-one-array-also-remove-duplicates)

Comment: @RobinSingh, in your link I find this $result = array_unique(array_merge($A,$B)); and with loop for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($result); $i<$n; $i++) { echo $result[$i] . ', ' . $B[$i] . '<br />'; }, but the result is not 100% that I need.thak you I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `for` loop, you need a change in your code:

```
<?php
// Input
$A = array('0' => '1451', '1' => '1451', '2' => '1452', '3' => '1452', '4' => '1453', '5' => '1453', '6' => '1457', '7' => '1460');
$B = array('0' => '22',   '1' => '23',   '2' => '22',   '3' => '23',   '4' => '22',   '5' => '23',   '6' => '',     '7' => '');

// Output array
$O = array();    
for ($i = 0, $n = count($A); $i < $n; $i++) {
    $O[$A[$i]][] = $B[$i];
}

// Print the output
foreach ($O as $key => $items) {
    echo $key." = ".implode(',', $items)."<br>";
}   
?>
```