# Removing duplicate keys when merging arrays in php

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json

I have 2 arrays with duplicate keys. Some times only one of the arrays with duplicate keys may have actual data. While other array has keys with null or empty values.

I am using `json_encode(array_merge($row2,$row3));` to merge arrays and return in JSON format.

Now if `$row2['subject]` does not have value and only `$row3['subject']` has value. And sometimes it may be opposite.

How can I get only duplicate keys with value in it?

I have 2 different tables in with few of them with same column names. I don't have control over it: I can't redesign or change any MySQL schema. I am using `mysqlidb` library and this code:

```php
$db->where('id',$row['student_frkey']);
$row2=$db->getOne('student_data');

$db->where('id',$row2['bind_profile']);
$row3=$db->getOne('student_profiles');

echo json_encode(array_merge($row2,$row3));
```

As I said there are duplicate columns in `student_profiles` table and `student_data`. Say I have data empty for duplicate column `subject` in `student_data` sometimes and present in `student_profiles`. But some other times it may be opposite. But at ant given time and query, only one of the duplicate column may have data. So my question is: How I can I return the   key which has data after merging array?

Comment: Use `array_filter()` on each array to remove empty elements before merging. That doesn't solve the issue when both arrays have not-empty values, but you haven't defined what should happen in that case.

Comment: please show sample data with expected outcome, your question is unclear.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13469882/8607640

Comment: @Psycho doesnt  array_unique() eliminate  duplicate columns with data exist ?.  I will try

Comment: thanks for the update. However, you're still not showing sample data with expected outcome. I.e. please show us a sample of `$row2` and `$row3` arrays and the expected merged result. Then show us what you currently get after merging the arrays, i.e. the actual result. Thanks.

Comment: @berend json out put after merging is  below {"id":30,"bind_student":"78","bind_profile":"30","student_name":"RAJESH","'subject":"SCIENCE","conf_password":"bt12hj","conf_link":"create.onclass.in","school_name":"Indira Public School"}

As i said i have 2 tables with same columns called subject , only one of them may have data at any given time.  After merging how can display only the column which has value in it .  Now it is always  return first array key after merging irrespective of its value exist or not .

Comment: @psycho  array_unique does not solve my issue because it is  working on duplicate values . I need to work on duplicate keys and return only duplicate key with data .

Comment: please provide us in your question with actual data with `what you get` and `what you want`. Provide us expected output like you may say- `it gives me [1,2] but I want [1]`

Comment: echo json_encode(array_merge(array_filter($row2),array_filter($row3))); worked for me . But it is removing all keys with null data . But I wanted to see keys with null values in out put except duplicate keys with empty value . So I am inserting  a dummy value for other columns . So my problem solved .