# issue in merge two array and remove duplicate entry in php

Tags: php, arrays, function

I've merged two arrays. A duplicate entry is a deleted.
Let me explain the as an example

```php
$array1 = array("2", "3");
$array2 = array("3", "5", "4", "7", "8", "2", "10");
```

I have merged array1 and array2
$oneMeargeArr = array_merge( $array1, $array2);

Array merged output

```
$oneMeargeArr = Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 3 [3] => 5 [4] => 4 [5] => 7 [6] => 8 [7] => 2 [8] => 10)
```

after that remove duplicate entry

```
$oneMeargeArr = Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 5 [2] => 4 [3] => 7 [4] => 8 [5] => 2 [6] => 10)
```

I get such an output

```php
$test_array = Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 5 [2] => 4 [3] => 7 [4] => 8 [5] => 2 [6] => 10)
```

I want such an output

```php
$test_array = Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 4 [2] => 7 [3] => 8 [4] => 10)
```

Comment: Where is the code that merges you arrays?

Comment: You probably need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469803/php-merging-two-arrays-into-one-array-also-remove-duplicates

Comment: @RobbertvandenBogerd $array1 = array("2", "3");
$array2 = array("3", "5", "4", "7", "8", "2", "10");
I have merged array1 and array2 $oneMeargeArr = array_merge( $array1, $array2);

Array merged output $oneMeargeArr = Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 3 [3] => 5 [4] => 4 [5] => 7 [6] => 8 [7] => 2 [8] => 10)

after that remove duplicate entry $oneMeargeArr = Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 5 [2] => 4 [3] => 7 [4] => 8 [5] => 2 [6] => 10)

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```php
$array1 = array("2", "3");
$array2 = array("3", "5", "4", "7", "8", "2", "10");

$test_array = array_diff(array_merge($array1, $array2), array_intersect($array1, $array2));

var_dump($test_array);
```

The above code will output:

```php
array(5) {
  [3]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "7"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [8]=>
  string(2) "10"
}
```

And to reset the array index start from `0` again do following:

```php
array_values($test_array);
```

Comment: this solution is working but my array is Array
$array1 = (
[0] => Array([id] => 44 [user_id] => 2 [name] => jina_testl [profilePhoto] =>))
)  $array2 = Array([0] => Array(
[id] => 2 [user_id] => 3 [name] => demo_test1 [profilePhoto] => ) [1] => Array([id] => 45 [user_id] => 2 [name] => jina_testl [profilePhoto] =>)) Your solution for this array does not work. i have compare with user_id